# Locomotive CMS bundle install fails rmagick 2.12.2 error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick, locomotivecms

I am trying to install Locomotive CMS but I am getting an error regarding rmagick upon installation:

```
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.12.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.12.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I checked the log and this is the error rmagick is showing:

```
$ gem install rmagick -v '2.12.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:107:in `<main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
extconf.rb:107:in `<main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for /usr/bin/clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.3.5... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
Can't install RMagick 2.12.2. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
    --with-MagickCorelib
    --without-MagickCorelib
    --with-Magicklib
    --without-Magicklib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rmagick-2.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.12.2/gem_make.out
```

I've found similar issues on SO and Google but I've been trying all sorts of fixes for about 3 hours now and still can't get it to work. Please advise, thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you post the contents of your `mkmf.log` file? `cat ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/ext/RMagick/mkmf.log`

Comment: Hi Jamon, unfortunately I don't have the log files anymore. I ended up using RVM to use Ruby 1.9.3 by default, and after that, the LocomotiveCMS installation went through perfectly.

Let me know if you figure it out, would be great to run my Engine on the latest version of Ruby.

Comment: I ended up having to reinstall Ruby 2.1 using ruby-install with this command: `ruby-install ruby 2.1.0 -- --enable-shared --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin` -- after that, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Of course, `brew install ruby-install` first.